# Как использовать интерфейс IDisposable?

Tags: c#

У меня в задании написано: *"Класс должен реализовывать интерфейс IDisposable, и в методе Dispose освобождать занятые ресурсы."*
Пример  необходимого мне класса представлен на [сайте](http://www.sdss.jhu.edu/~tamas/bytes/fftwcsharp.html). 
**Как реализовать интерфейс IDisposable и метод Dispose в данном случае?**

или это реализуется просто:

```
using (fftwtest TEST = new fftwtest())
{
   //обработка, вызов методов, свойств, интерфейсов
}
```

или

```
fftwtest TEST = new fftwtest()
   //обработка, вызов методов, свойств, интерфейсов
TEST.Dispose();
```

На основе того что представлено на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) написал код:

```
public class fftwtest : IDisposable
{
    IntPtr pin, pout;
    float[] fin, fout;
    IntPtr fplan1;

    private bool disposed = false;

    public void InitFFTW(int n)
    {
        pin = fftwf.malloc(n * 8);
        pout = fftwf.malloc(n * 8);
        fin = new float[n * 2];
        fout = new float[n * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i++)
            fin[i] = i % 50;

        //copy managed arrays to unmanaged arrays
        Marshal.Copy(fin, 0, pin, n * 2);

        //create a few test transforms
        fplan1 = fftwf.dft_1d(n, pin, pout, fftw_direction.Forward, fftw_flags.Estimate);
    }

    public void TestAll()
    {
        TestPlan(fplan1);
    }

    public void TestPlan(IntPtr plan)
    {
            fftwf.execute(plan);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);       //освобождение вызвали вручную
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); //не хотим, чтобы GC вызвал деструктор
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed
            // and unmanaged resources.
            if (disposing)
            {

            }

            fftwf.free(pin);
            fftwf.free(pout);
            fftwf.destroy_plan(fplan1);

            // Note disposing has been done.
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
 ~fftwtest()
    {
        // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here.
        // Calling Dispose(false) is optimal in terms of
        // readability and maintainability.
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

**Правильно или неправильно?**

Comment: Все верно, только в данном случае `if (disposing)` блок тебе не нужен. Если в твоем классе будут использоваться другие IDisposable, тогда в этом блоке надо вызывать на них явно Dispose. Иначе его можно убрать, для чистоты так сказать.

Comment: На самом деле, как раз рекомендуется, что если метод освобождения был уже вызван, то при повторном вызове он должен немедленно вернуть управление. Другое дело, что, возможно, проверку можно было бы поместить в явный Dispose(). При вызове через финализатор система сама разберётся.

А вот саму проверку для уменьшения количества лечтницеобразного кода я бы порекомендовал переписать в виде if (this.disposed) return;

Comment: Согласен с Modus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В классе представленном по ссылке весь код из метода `FreeFFTW` должен перекочевать в метод `Dispose(bool disposing)` при реализации интерфейса. А саму технику реализации можешь посмотреть в [статье MSDN об IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). После того как реализуешь интерфейс сможешь использовать примеры приведенные тобой в вопросе.